# Split Text into different lengths in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, split, vba

I am currently working on a database in access 2010 that will scan a barcode in PDF147 format.

Basically what the idea is to take the barcode information and split it into the different text boxes of the form.

Ex:

```
SRGTR17385JOHN      DOE       DASD17366M
```

From there I would want to take characters 10-20 and apply it to the first name text-box, then take characters 21-30 and apply it to the last name text box, lastly take the 40th character and apply it to the middle initial text box.

Hope this was specific enough.

Comment: For the barcode read out there is 10 spaces for both the first name and last name..system took the spaces out. 85JOHN567890DOE4567890DAS. The numbers represent the spaces.

Answer (score 2):

If you are obtaining the barcode info from a table, the following query will split out the pieces:

```
SELECT Table1.BARCODE, Left([BARCODE],10) AS BCOnly, Mid([barcode],11,10) AS FirstName, Mid([barcode],21,10) AS LastName
FROM Table1;
```

If you want VBA code:

```
Me.txtBarcode = Left([RS!BARCODE],10)
Me.txtFirstName = Mid([RS!barcode],11,10) 
Me.txtLastName = Mid([RS!barcode],21,10)
```